# Make the cardView scroll while anchor is active

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a problem I want the orange cardView on the top to be like this:

[image]

and when the user Scorll I have to make this orange card scroll as well
but I used coordinate layout with anchor for the card

I've to make it invisible when the user scrolls away a little bit but I have this:

[image]

my question is how to make this orange cardview to stay and scroll with other layout elements?

my xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/profile_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
            app:elevation="3dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
                    android:text="Mark Davis"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_below="@id/username"
                    android:text="IT consuler"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:elevation="3dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Personal Information"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:text="Personal Inforamtion"
                    android:elevation="3dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="User Name"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_margin"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="User Name"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Email"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Display name"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Display name"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Password"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Password"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/app_margin"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_margin"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/profile_card"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center|top"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorAccent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonLove"
        android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_edit"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/button_white"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, when the user scrolls you want to scroll the card with the orange logo as well as hide the logo at the same time?

Comment: Not really, when the user scrolls down I want only the orange logo to be scrolled as well not to be hided or the anchor corrupt, I can use RelativeLayout instead of coordinateLayout but what about the FAB?